# How can I find matches between two group of three columns independent of row order in Excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel

To clarify, I would like to automate the process of finding matches by highlighting each found match like this:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/SY2pN.jpg]

Thank you!

Comment: use conditional formatting with countifs.

Answer (score 0):

Based on Scott Craner’s reply, I would add the details.

Select the cells that you want to apply rules, in my sample, I select A2:C10 > go to Home > Conditional Formatting > New Rule > Use a formula to determine which cells to format > enter the formula `=COUNTIFS($E$2:$E$12,$A2,$F$2:$F$12,$B2,$G$2:$G$12,$C2)` > Format > choose the color to fill. 
When opening **Manage Rules**, it looks like the following picture.

[image]

You may also try the more complex formula for the left table *=AND(COUNTIF($A$2:$C10,$E2)>0,COUNTIF($A$2:$C10,$F2)>0,COUNTIF($A$2:$C10,$G2)>0)*

Do the same for right data. The range is E2:G12, the formula is `=COUNTIFS($A$2:$A10,$E2,$B$2:$B10,$F2,$C$2:$C10,$G2)`. In **Manage Rules** it looks like the screenshot below.

[image]